# Where the heck is the $-2x$ coming from?

Tags: calculus

$$5^2+(x-1)^2 = x$$
It breaks down to $25 + x^2 -2x +1 = x$.
All I'm not getting is the $-2x$. $\quad(x)(x)= x^2$; $(-1)(-1)=1$.
So where the heck is the $-2x$ coming from?

Comment: $-1-1 = -2$, moreover $(x+a)(x+a) = x^2 + ax + ax + a^2 = x^2 + 2ax + a^2$

Comment: The square doesn't get distributed the way you think. $(x-1)^2=(x\cdot x)-x-x+(-1)\cdot (-1) = (x^2)-2x+1$

Comment: Ah so in other words it's actually distributed (x-1)(x-1)? Makes sense.... everything inside multiplied by everything inside.... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2\implies (x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply distributive property of multiplication:
$$(a+b)\times c = (a\times c) + (b \times c).$$
This is:
$$(a+b)\times(c+d)=(a\times(c+d))+(b\times(c+d)).$$

In your example:
$$(x-1)^2 = (x-1)\times(x-1) = (x\times(x-1))+(-1\times(x+-1))$$
$$=x\times x - x -x +1 = x^2 -2x +1.$$

Recall that a power $t$ of $n$ gives $n^t$ which is $n\cdot n\cdot ... \cdot n$  $t$-times, no matter what $n$ is.